Use of the passive in this sentence?

The character enters into a room without permission and  woman tells him "You shouldn't touch without permission" and "the owner of that room treasures those stuff". It's not her room so she's simply admonishing him.
To which he apologizes and the woman tells him

私に謝られても

I'm a bit stumbled here by the use of the passive... gooling around it seems akin to a way of say?  Why is the passive being used? From the dialog I can gather it's something like "NO point apologizing to me"?

Duplicate? 私に言われても versus 私が言われても

This is an example of suffering passive like 雨に降られた.

私に謝る
to apologize to me
私に謝られる
to apologize to me (causing me trouble)
(Since the speaker is the woman, this 私に is "to me" rather than "by me".)

That is, "you" apologized to me, and "I" was negatively affected by it. Since this room does not belong to her, she is not in a position to accept the apology and say "no problem" in the first place. So she is suggesting such an apology makes no sense and is even slightly annoying to her.
Related: Function of に in this passive construction
